# How to write the type of that nested grouped data C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I grouped my data and I want to send this data to the view with the model. How can I write property into the viewmodel

WorkPlan Class

```
public class WorkPlan:IEntity
{
    public int WorkPlanId { get; set; }
    public int PlanNumber { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Lesson { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

WorkPlanViewModel

```
public class WorkPlanViewModel:BaseViewModel
{

    public List<WorkPlan> WorkPlans { get; set; }

    public WorkPlan WorkPlan { get; set; }

}
```

Action

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    WorkPlanViewModel model=new WorkPlanViewModel();
    model.Message=new Message();
    var allWorkPlan = workPlanService.GetAll();

    var groupPlan = allWorkPlan.GroupBy(p => p.PlanNumber)
                    .Select(p => new {PlanNumber=p.Key, Day= p.GroupBy(b => b.Day).ToList() } ).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

groupPlan is my grouped data

Comment: Thanks for the additional code.  I tested out my code and it seems to work.  Note you need to have a property on the ViewModel that is a `List<GroupPlan>` not `List<WorkPlan>`.  Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, can you up vote it as well?  The rep extra points come in handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class that reflects that anonymous type and add it as a property to your view model.

Controller/Action Code - note the `new GroupPlan` code below in the `Select`

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
vm.GroupPlans = allWorkPlan.GroupBy(p => p.PlanNumber)
                    .Select(p => new GroupPlan { PlanNumber = p.Key, Day = p.GroupBy(b => b.Day).ToList() }).ToList();
```

GroupPlan Class

```
public class GroupPlan
{
    public int PlanNumber { get; set; }
    public List<IGrouping<string, WorkPlan>> Day { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel Class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<GroupPlan> GroupPlans { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. I get this error when I do it the way you say.       Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int PlanNumber, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, WeekPlan.Entities.Concrete.WorkPlan>> Day>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WeekPlan.Entities.ComplexType.GroupedWorkPlan>' WeekPlan.MvcWebUI E:\Program Denemelerim\WeekPlan\WeekPlan\WeekPlan.MvcWebUI\Controllers\WorkPlanController.cs 59 Active

Comment: Since you didn't provide your code for `WorkPlan` or `allWorkPlan` I wasn't able to test my code.  I had to make a few guesses.  Please update your question with that code and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, don't skip over the `new GroupPlan` code inside my answer, based on your error message that may be part of the problem?